# Exception when trying to start a program when a file already exists

Tags: java, file

I have an application that writes text to a File. If the File doesn't exist, it is created.

When I run the application for the first time, it all works correctly and the File is created. However, every subsequent time causes the application to crash. Could you please help explain why it doesn't work more than once.

My code is as follows...

```
public class Apples {

    Formatter x;
    File file = new File("myfile.txt");

    public Apples() {

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                x = new Formatter("myfile.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("There was an error creating the file");
            }

            System.out.println("The file was created");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("The file already exists");
            }

        x.format("%s", "text");
        x.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Apples a = new Apples();
    }

}
```

Comment: System.out.println("error");  - Please make it print out the whole detail from the System.out.println("error : "+ e.getMessage());

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the problem is a `NullPointerException` on the line `x.format("%s", "text");` because you aren't assigning a value to `x` if the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Second time `x` is null because you don't init it.